# Error: "Failed to start container" when trying to launch euler's app

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox, shinyproxy

I’m having problem launching the euler’s app on ShinyProxy.
I can build the docker image without problem, and if I run it directly on Docker using the command:

```
docker run -it -p 3838:3838 openanalytics/shinyproxy-template
```

the app works normally.
However, when I try to run it on shinyproxy I get the following error:

```
Status code: 500

Message: Failed to start container: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

I’m using Docker Toolbox on Windows 10. The docker’s daemon runs at IP 192.168.99.100

Answer (score 0):

I have just cloned the repo and did a docker build -t myname/mytag . (inside the repo where its Dockerfile is) and then run it as:

```
docker run -p 3838:3838 myname/mytag
```

And everything worked as you can see from the images attached.[image]

[image]

So I can confirm that there's nothing wrong with the image or with the [repo](https://github.com/openanalytics/shinyproxy-template)

Comment: Yes, it's seems that it's a shinyproxy problem, maybe it cannot connect to the docker daemon? I'm pretty sure that it needs some specific configuration in order to make it run on windows but I have no idea where to start...

Comment: @miditower if I were you, I would create a bug on the repo itself, as the author of this project might know more about it :)